# Use GnuLib without Autotools

Tags: c, windows

My platform (MinGW) does not define the macro `ETIMEDOUT`, among [**others**](http://gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/errno_002eh). It was suggested in another question that this can be fixed with GnuLib.

I would like to do this but it appears any project wishing to use GnuLib must also use [**Autotools**](http://wiki.opencsw.org/adding-gnulib). My project simply has a Makefile.

How could I supplement my platform with GnuLib without adding Autotools as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it easier, just add the folliwng in your header file instead of something like gnulib..

```
#ifndef ETIMTDOUT
#define ETIMEDOUT 10060
//if you have WSAETIMEDOUT defined, then you can just
//#define ETIMEOUT WSAETIMEDOUT 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

*Paul Eggert* wrote [a patch to use gnulib without automake](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnulib/2017-03/msg00028.html). It is available on master branch since 2017-03-13. Just call `gnulib-tool` with `--gnu-make`.